# How to Ignore Single Quote in SQL Searching

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping, single-quotes

My database contains string entries with single quotes. Like **Women's** Property Rights.

1. When a user searches in search field by typing exact **Women's** Property Rights title (Typing with single quote), search result displays related titles and works fine.
2. BUT I want that if a user forgot the single quotes (') typing with title, the result should display the titles and ignores single quote (').

[Search Result with Single Quote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekeni.png)
[Without Single Quote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9WS4.png)

So I want a suggestion to how can I ignore single quote in SQL Search.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The answer is heavily dependent on the specific database you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: If this is the only "special searching rule" you want to implement a simple indexed generated column will do. However, if you want to start adding more and more special searching rules, then a "test search" solution will be the way to go. PostgreSQL implements a great text search engine for free, if that's your database.

Comment: @jarlh I am using MySQL DB with php programming.